# PathVariable is being trimmed after dot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a `REST` service, that has a path:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login_name:{loginName}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<User> findByLoginName(@PathVariable("loginName") String loginName) {
...
}
```

I need my path to be with `:`, I'm not allowed to specify parameters after `?`, as usual.

So I call it as `localhost:8080/user/login_name:testUser@test.com`

Everything is fine, except for one thing:

`loginName` is being trimmed after a dot. So it's not `testUser@test.com`, it's `testUser@test`.
How can I avoid this?